# How to get numbers in different positions

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get only one number and one circle when I click the button so if I click the button 3 times I will get the 3 numbers with the circles obviously. It's suppose to be lottery numbers appearing after every click but I have no idea how can I do that.

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse first = new Ellipse();
        first.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        first.Height = 70;
        first.Width = 70;
        first.Margin = new Thickness(50, 100, 0, 0);
        caPaper.Children.Add(first);

        Ellipse second = new Ellipse();
        second.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        second.Height = 70;
        second.Width = 70;
        second.Margin = new Thickness(150, 100, 0, 0);
        caPaper.Children.Add(second);

        Ellipse third = new Ellipse();
        third.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        third.Height = 70;
        third.Width = 70;
        third.Margin = new Thickness(250, 100, 0, 0);
        caPaper.Children.Add(third);

        Random rd = new Random();

        TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
        txt1.FontSize = 20;
        txt1.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        txt1.Text = " " + rd.Next(1, 45);
        Canvas.SetTop(txt1, 120);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txt1, 70);
        caPaper.Children.Add(txt1);

        TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();
        txt2.FontSize = 20;
        txt2.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        txt2.Text = " " + rd.Next(1, 45);
        Canvas.SetTop(txt2, 120);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txt2, 170);
        caPaper.Children.Add(txt2);

        TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
        txt3.FontSize = 20;
        txt3.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        txt3.Text = " " + rd.Next(1, 45);
        Canvas.SetTop(txt3, 120);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txt3, 270);
        caPaper.Children.Add(txt3);

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        caPaper.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: Does it help to call `caPaper.Children.Clear();` at the beginning of `btnGo_Click`? Another possibility is to disable the button when clicked `btnGo.Enabled = false;` to allow the user to click it only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52726228/3825611), your approach could use a bit of tweaking. WPF has some really powerful data binding features to build UI MUCH MORE pain free. However to answer your question...

It looks as though the only thing that is 'unique' per ball is the margin of the ball and the left value in `Canvas.SetLeft`

You should be able to derive those values based on the number of children in your canvas. For example something like this:

```
int marginLeft = 50 + (caPaper.Children.Length * 100);

Ellipse newBall = new Ellipse();
newBall.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
newBall.Height = 70;
newBall.Width = 70;
newBall.Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, 100, 0, 0);
caPaper.Children.Add(newBall);
```

You'll want to adjust that of course but I wanted to give you an idea to work with. Also, the same will need to be done for the text. Then, each time you click it, it will create them in relation to the number of children it already has.

Comment: caPaper.Children.Length shows an error. 'Length' is underlined

Comment: Might be Count(). I’m on my phone.

Comment: It does not show an error with Count(), but I still don't really know how to do it. Do i have to just change to 'marginLeft' in every Ellipse?

Comment: You’ll just have one now. Every time you click the button it should add another.

Comment: Oh I figured out the circles but not the can't get the texts on them.

Answer (score 3):

### This is 100% the **wrong** approach to this.

You should *never* be dynamically creating UI controls like this. It's so wrong its not worth figuring out what is wrong in your code.

Use MVVM, it will make your life much, much, much easier. Your lottery numbers are *data*, the balls, a visual representation of that data. So in your VM:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Draws {get;} = new ObservableCollection<int>();

// Invoked from command, or could be a click handler until you learn commands
public AddDraw()
{
     int draw = GetNextDraw(); //Left as an exercise
     Draws.Add(draw)
}
```

Now that the data is handled, we need to display it. An `ItemsControl` is how you display collections, use the `ItemTemplate` to control how the number is displayed (the ball) and `ItemsPanel` to control the layout (a horizontal `WrapPanel` is probably what you want):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Draws}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
             <Ellipse Fill="Red/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
          </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

That's off the top of my head so I may have a property or class wrong. Intellisense should correct it pretty quickly though.

Once its set up you can add margin, change the colors, whatever. This design is what WPF was built for, take advantage of it.

<sub>Disclaimer: I have had to deal with creating UI controls at all ONCE. In 7 years of professional WPF work, and only because the data structure being represented was incredibly complex (and not similar to how it was being represented).</sub>

Comment: The thing is I just started using c# I had 3 courses only and the teacher doesn't really teach much but we have never changed anything in the XAML. What you wrote is pretty complicated for me but thanks anyways.

Comment: @MinJie Understandable, but this is the wrong path, you are going to learn *so* many bad habits. Either find a way to get your instructor to let you do things the right way, or at least learn it on the side. Getting started with MVVM will make your head spin, but it is worth it.

Comment: @MinJie "we have never changed anything in the XAML" => A guarantee that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: You could be right. I'm so new to the whole programming thing so I just try to follow what the teacher does but she's barely explain things tbh. Appreciate the help tho!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET chill.. you can see he’s obviously new to programming. This may be wrong in a large scale but is absolutely ok when he’s trying to learn fundamentals. Any seasoned developer will agree that this isn’t the “best” approach, but that’s not to say there isn’t value in doing things wrong before learning “better” ways to do them.

Comment: @Cory There's learning from experience... and there's just doing things the wrong way (a.k.a. `goto`) If you want to learn procedural UI code fine; but if you want to learn WPF (or to be more clear, most modern UI frameworks) getting a bunch of bad habits right away isn't a good approach IMO. Also see my disclaimer... while you can certainly learn programming principles by doing things this way, the reality is you don't actually do this in industry.

Comment: @Cory Besides; wouldn't you rather get taught some good OOP foundations than how to procedurally deal with UI ;)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree. 100%. I'm coming more from the lines of also 'understanding' why to do something a certain way. IMO it's important for younger developers to wrap their head around getting something working and then progressing to doing things more suitable for the situation. That said, I should have started my answer with "this is wrong, but here's how go get your code working".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET lol, I'd rather never touch a UI another day in my life. But that's my preference.

Comment: @Cory I 100% agree in turn on getting something working first... Its just that if that's really where the dev is coming from (that MVVM is just way too much) I would *personally* say they should get that experience on console apps instead of getting into a "WinForms" mindset that easily could haunt them later on. Not a knock on the OP of course; rather the instructor.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, for sure. Unless the very next lesson is *we did this the wrong way, now lets show you the right way* then the instructor has no business having them in WPF. I don't think presentation should ever be part of programming class, but that's me. Unless the class is geared at the presentation layer (mobile design/web design/etc) then you should have your head stuck in a console. Again, my opinion.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks for the back and forth. I've updated my post to include the disclaimer "don't do it this way" as I do feel that is important. Great catch and way to keep developers honest!

Comment: I'll second everything Bradley has said.  After many years of WinForms development, and C++/MFC work before that, I am now about 18 months into using WPF full time.  And I can tell you it's been a painful transition at times.  However, the more I learn the more I have come to appreciate just how well it all works, and how easily you can get where you're going, without all of the trudgery that forms work could be.  Including examples such as OP is being forced to endure.